# husky openni_tracker

Tags: husky, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new in ROS and I want to make husky follow a person.
I searched information about how to do it but I haven't found anything.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks.

I'm working with Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS hydro version.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208099/husky-openni_tracker/) by [hr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/22292/hr1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you mean following a person and obstacle avoidance at the same time ? using kinect?

---

Originally posted by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) with karma: 150 on 2015-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hr1](https://answers.ros.org/users/22292/hr1/) on 2015-05-04**:
Only following a person using kinect.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-04**:
it should be easy. get the openni tracker file and get z value for a specific joint. Then implement feedback control loop